# Facing issue while running MR Job on Yarn

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying run a MR job on Yarn. While running the MR job , the job gets stuck while cleaning up the staging dir. created by the process. below is the log snippet

```
2022-03-24 00:12:48 IST INFO  [defaultEventExecutorGroup-2-1] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy  - Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
2022-03-24 00:12:49 IST INFO  [defaultEventExecutorGroup-2-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat  - Total input paths to process : 3
2022-03-24 00:12:49 IST INFO  [defaultEventExecutorGroup-2-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - number of splits:3
2022-03-24 00:12:49 IST INFO  [defaultEventExecutorGroup-2-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Submitting tokens for job: job_1648055218115_0023
2022-03-24 00:12:49 IST INFO  [defaultEventExecutorGroup-2-1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Cleaning up the staging area /user/pk/.staging/job_1648055218115_0023
```

Below is the dir structure on HDFS

```
drwx------   - pk supergroup          0 2022-03-24 00:12 /user/pk/.staging
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
  </property>
<property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Can someone suggest how we can resolve this issue ?

Comment: 1) `mapred.job.tracker` is never used past Hadoop v1, so whatever method you used to setup the cluster is incorrect 2) You should change `localhost` everywhere to use the actual external IP/hostname of those machines 3) Does the user running the job have the permissions needed to clean up the folder?

Comment: Yes. The directory is created by the process using use pk and it should have access

Comment: If you open the YARN UI and look at the job there, is the application getting any cpu/memory resources? Or is it stuck in ACCEPTED / SUBMITTED state?